# AEM 6.1 Maven Dependency Resolution

Tags: maven, adobe, aem

I'm using AEM6.1 with Maven as build manager.

I want to extend the ***com.day.cq.dam.core.process.ThumbnailProcess*** class.
Using the AEM buit-in dependency resolver

> system/console/depfinder

it seems that the class should be contained in

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>com.day.cq.dam</groupId> 
  <artifactId>cq-dam-core</artifactId> 
  <version>5.8.172</version> 
  <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>
```

Anyway the [Adobe nexus repo](https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/) does not contain this version and all the older do not provide the above class.

I wish to know how to manage this problem.
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the latest version Adobe pushed everything into a giant dependencies jar.

Put this at the end of your POM:

```
<depen­dency>
   <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
   <arti­fac­tId>uber-jar</arti­fac­tId>
   <ver­sion>6.1.0</ver­sion>
   <scope>pro­vided</scope>
   <clas­si­fier>obfuscated-apis</clas­si­fier>
</depen­dency>
```