# AEM - what maven repo has cq-commons?

Tags: maven, aem

I'm working on a port from CQ5.6.1 to AEM6.2. I am attempting to update my dependency versions, but I'm running into a problem with cq-commons.
I need to satisfy a dependency on the package `com.day.cq.commons.jcr`. The package dependency tool tells me that my maven file needs the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>
    <artifactId>cq-commons</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.22</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am using the repository at https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/day/cq/cq-commons/
The latest version there is 5.8.2, so maven is telling me that the POM is missing. Where do I get this, if not Adobe's public repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the apis have been bundled together and are available here:
https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/adobe/aem/uber-jar/6.2.0/

This is unfortunate, because it makes the information in the package dependency tool misleading - I'm OK with the bundle; I just wish they had kept the pieces too.

See also:
[AEM 6.1 Maven Dependency Resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675700/aem-6-1-maven-dependency-resolution?rq=1)